# Hostname change for Postfix?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, postfix, hostname

I have successfully setup a small home web server (Apache2), and now desire to proceed in setting up Postfix, SMTP and IMAP services.

Concerning the hostname of the system vs. the mail server name, is there a need to change the hostname to the domain name, or can one simply use "mail.domain.com" in the Postfix setup area? I am not entirely familiar with hostname changing, and have previously "broken" a setup on a mail server (it also ran DNS) by executing hostname changes. But now I am not running DNS services on this box. So am I free to make changes without messing up Apache2 or anything I have set up previously?

Thank you

Comment: I think this is an "XY Problem", that is, "changing my old hostname to my actual domain name" is NOT the correct solution to the real problem.  What have you tried, what didn't work, etc.?

Comment: I do not anticipate any problems changing the hostname but you need to understand the difference between hostname and domain name.

Comment: also webmin is not in the official ubuntu repositories so although a problem is not anticipated, if you have one you will need to file with webmin.

Comment: @waltinator, I haven't tried anything yet.  But it is my understanding that if you are going to run a mail server, that perhaps it is best to use the domain name for that machine?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thank you for the Webmin info, however, I am not sure I would file anything with anyone should a problem arise.  I am asking the question in advance as I know no one else to speak to regarding Ubuntu and it's behavior.

Comment: To underline waltinator's statement: here's an [explanation of the “XY problem”](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411), why one should avoid such questions and suggestions on how to restate the question to tackle the underlying issue.

Comment: If you have a problem with webmin, and do not file a bug report, then your problem will never be solved.